# HTML math format for uploading to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

When I upload an HTML document with math to Google Drive and convert to a Google document, is there a math format which Google will convert to it's own math format?

So far I have tried LaTeX math as MathJax and wrapped in `<eq>` tags, and MathML.  Neither are recognized.

I note that Google Docs does recognize and convert formulas in .docx files.